# Unrepeated random() query

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to display 3 random images from SQLite database horizontally. Since it's impossible to make a horizontal `ListView`, I made 3 ListViews next to each other inside a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout`:

```
final ListView g = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText1);
final ListView h = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText2);
final ListView i = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText3);

g.setOnItemClickListener(this);
h.setOnItemClickListener(this);
i.setOnItemClickListener(this);
// Set the adapter to our custom adapter (below)

g.setAdapter(new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.toplist,
    managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(Provider.CONTENT_URI,
    Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
    Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE}, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 1"),
    new String[] { Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, new int[] {R.id.image1}));

h.setAdapter(new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.toplist,
    managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(Provider.CONTENT_URI,
    Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
    Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE}, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 1"),
    new String[] { Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, new int[] {R.id.image1}));

i.setAdapter(new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.toplist,
    managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(Provider.CONTENT_URI,
    Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
    Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE}, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 1"),
    new String[] { Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, new int[] {R.id.image1}));
```

Everything works, except the random shown images should be distinct from each other. Since I use 3 different ListViews, sometimes they show the same random images. How can I solve my problem? Maybe by modifying `"RANDOM() LIMIT 1"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FSM save us ... you're still here

ListView for single item is a bad idea

just put 3 ImagesView in Layout and do something like this

```
final ImageView[] images = new ImageView[3];
ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(this);

images[0] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
images[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
images[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

int counter = 0;

    Cursor c = managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(Provider.CONTENT_URI,
                    Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
                    Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE}, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 3");
  if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()){
     do{
       String url = c.getString(1);
       images[counter].setTag(url);
       loader.DisplayImage(url, this, images[counter]);
       counter++;
     }while(c.moveToNext());
  }
```

Comment: you told me once I better use the listview -__- anyway thanks, why are you always there following me? hehe. I wanna make the OnClickListener how should I declare the long id, OnClick only allows me View as its argument

Comment: how about the onClickListener? How to make it possible for me to call the long id? : public void onClick(View v,long id) {
  Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
  listIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
    Provider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
    .toString(id)));
  startActivity(listIntent);
  }

Comment: ... now u need to change ImageLoader class  and not use stringUrl as a tag for ImageView but `class MyTag { public String url; public Object TagInTag; }` in loop you should store value of c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)) in MyTag.TagInTag and add this (MyTag) as a Tag to imageView ... you should also add onClickListener to imageView in Listener you should take back TagInTag(where you store _id of Project) and open Details with this _id ... and, no i'll not wirte code for you anymore ;P

Comment: or ... Build static HashMap<ImageView, long> aaa; and in loop add this code aaa.put(images[counter], c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID))); then you can use this hash to obtain _id in onClickListener

Comment: onClickListener has only 1 param `View v` so you can  use my first advice and get id like this `MyTag tag = (MyTag)v.getTag(); long id = (long)tag.TagInTag;` or second advice and do this like `long id = aaa.get(v);`

Comment: Looks like there's one problem, so I chose your 2nd advice it works properly! Like the 3 random images are different between each other, and clickable to the DetailsActivity..BUT, everytime I open the ListView, then I hit back, the random images aren't clickable. Do you know where's the problem?

Comment: `HashMap<ImageView, Long> aaa = new HashMap<ImageView, Long>();` ---> I put this as Global Variable. Here's the loop--->  `if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()){
             do{
               String url = c.getString(1);
               images[counter].setTag(url);
               loader.DisplayImage(url, this, images[counter]);
               aaa.put(images[counter], c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
               counter++;
             }while(c.moveToNext());
          }`

Comment: and here's the onClick method: `  @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
             Intent listIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
             long id = aaa.get(v);
             listIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Provider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
            .toString(id)));
          startActivity(listIntent);
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Get the rowcount, pick your random numbers in the range 0 to rowcount-1 at the client, then use LIMIT to choose the nth row...